How do you interpret the solenoid direction?
My son had the following circuit diagram in a practice exam and was asked to construct the magnetic field from the solenoid, including the direction. The problem is, this diagram can be viewed from two different perspectives, one with the initial turn of the coil going into the page, and one with the initial turn of the coil coming out of the page. These produce magnetic fields in opposite directions. Is there a standard way to interpret such a circuit diagram?


I think the shape of the bending of the wires makes the magnetic field pointing along the axis of symmetry of this solenoid to be leftwards on this page.

It is impossible to say. The whole thing might even be two dimensional with the wires shorted.

I would assume by default the right-hand rule for winding the coils, since it would be more conventional (see right-hand rule, solenoid), and provide the full solution for this case. But it is worth informing the teacher/professor of this ambiguity.
